How to use web application as bluetooth receiver RSSI?
I want to create an indoor positioning on a web application. I tried using the Web Bluetooth API to receive RSSI, but it doesn't work.
Here is the code for receive bluetooth RSSI:
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>Web Bluetooth RSSI Example</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <button id="connectButton">Connect to ESP32</button>
       <p id="rssiValue">RSSI: <span id="rssi"></span> dBm</p>

       <script>
         const connectButton = document.getElementById('connectButton');
         const rssiValue = document.getElementById('rssi');

         async function connect() {
           try {
             const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
               filters: [{ services: ['4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914a'] }], 
          
             });

             // Continuously read RSSI
             device.addEventListener('advertisementreceived', (event) => {
               let rssi = event.rssi;
               rssiValue.textContent = `RSSI: ${rssi} dBm`;
             });

             connectButton.disabled = true; // Disable connect button after successful connection
           } catch (error) {
             console.error('Error connecting to Bluetooth device:', error);
           }
         }

         connectButton.addEventListener('click', connect);
       </script>
     </body>
     </html>


The Web Bluetooth WatchAdvertisement API (so as the event advertisementreceived) currently is only available behind the feature flag enable-web-bluetooth-new-permissions-backend.
Please also be advised that there is no plan to launch the WatchAdvertisement API and it will be replaced by the other API in the future. Please see https://g-issues.chromium.org/issues/40488594 for more detail.
